# How i can increase the size of a static plotly graph in svg format

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, data-analysis

how can I change size of a plotly graph rendered in static format.

```
fig.show(renderer='svg')
```

The svg format renders the graph in a static image and shrinks the graph too, how do i make it bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Image size can be specified in layout:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=900,
    height=900
)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]), layout=layout)
# save image if needed
pio.write_image(fig, 'fig1.svg')
fig.show(renderer='svg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing width and height to the `fig.show()` method:

```
fig.show(
    renderer='svg',
    width = 800, # or width = fig.layout.width, if you've set that already
    height = 600 # or height = fig.layout.height
)
```

One would expect Alexandra's answer to help, but it seems that with some versions of JupyterLab/plotly (in my case JupyterLab 3.0.16 with plotly 5 and kaleido 0.2), the static renderers don't automagically pick up the width and height specified in `fig.layout`.